# How to export drupal commerce products?

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to export products generated by [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module.
What can I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module with a plugin that fits your export format expectations such as [views datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) or [views_data_export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) for CSV, XML, etc

Comment: Hi i tried views_data_export but i dint find the solution . Is there any other module or drupal way of exporting content of products in drupal commerce site..

Answer (score 0):

I've used the solution suggested by pcambra.

I used the [views_data_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and it worked perfectly.

I read the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1820452) to find out how to use it.

1. Create a new view page and change the selection in the "Show" select box from "Content" to "Commerce Product". A whole set of different options become available.
2. Click "Continue & Edit".
3. Add the fields you want to have exported and a path (since it is a page view after all).
4. Add a display to your view and select "Data Export".
5. Give it a path and attach it to your first page view.

Then go to your page view url and you should see a CSV logo at the bottom of the screen that allows you to download a csv of what is displayed in the view.