# How to export complete products data to csv file

Tags: views, commerce, importing-exporting

We have a [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) site, and need to dump all the products data into another CMS. I checked the question, [How to export drupal commerce products?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/how-to-export-drupal-commerce-products)

After trying the [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module, I didn't find any option for CSV, Excel in the display.

What am I doing wrong?  I would like to export data to a CSV file or any other document so that I can easily import those products into [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **Views Bonus Pack** module too. You can see an option "Data Export" while adding a display in the view.

Comment: Views Bonus Pack is not available for drupal 7 @Ram

Comment: The question is for a site running the Drupal Commerce module, which is available for Drupal 7, and higher.